# Feynman diagram using feynmf - keeping lines straight after vertex, keeping line flat

Tags: diagrams, feynmf

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}
\usepackage{feynmp}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\DeclareGraphicsRule{*}{mps}{*}{}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\label{fig:ele_int_conv}
\centering
\parbox{0.5\textwidth}{
\begin{fmffile}{nonres}
\begin{fmfgraph*}(250,125)
\fmfleft{i1,i2}
\fmfright{o1,o2,o3,o4}
\fmf{fermion,lab=$q$}{i1,v1}
\fmf{fermion,lab=$\bar{q}$}{i2,v1}
\fmf{boson,lab=$Z$}{v1,v2}
\fmf{fermion,lab=$\mu^+$}{v2,v3,o1}
\fmf{boson,lab=$\gamma^*$}{v3,v4}
\fmf{fermion,lab=$e^+$ (missed)}{v4,o2}
\fmf{fermion,lab=$e^-$}{v4,o3}
\fmf{fermion,lab=$\mu^-$}{v2,o4}

\end{fmfgraph*}
\end{fmffile}
```

Minimal working example produces [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LhFhE.jpg) which is generally fine, but I would like to make the central "Z" line exactly horizontal, and I would like the \mu^+ line to be straight, and only have one label.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically what you need here are:

- phantom particles (to define the skeleton you want)
- `\fmffreeze` (to freeze the current shape before drawing further)

In the solution below, I've also used `tension` to make some of the lines shorter and `label.side` to stop the labels overlapping. These are slightly hack-y so you might want to play around with them. In particular, I moved the Z->mu mu vertex a bit to the left to leave space for everything that is happening on the right hand side. You may prefer another solution.

NB. I tested this with `feynmf` rather than `feynmp`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}
\usepackage{feynmf}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\DeclareGraphicsRule{*}{mf}{*}{}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\label{fig:ele_int_conv}
\centering
\parbox{0.5\textwidth}{
  \begin{fmffile}{nonres}
  \begin{fmfgraph*}(250,125)
    \fmfleft{i1,i2}
    \fmfright{o1,o2,o3,o4}
    \fmf{fermion,label=$q$,tension=2}{i1,v1}
    \fmf{fermion,label=$\bar{q}$,tension=2}{i2,v1}
    \fmf{boson,label=$Z$,tension=2}{v1,v2}
    \fmf{fermion,label=$\mu^-$}{v2,o4}
    \fmf{phantom}{v2,o1}
    \fmffreeze
    \fmf{phantom}{v2,v3}
    \fmf{phantom}{v2,v3,o1}
    \fmffreeze
    \fmf{fermion,label=$\mu^+$,label.side=right}{v2,o1}
    \fmf{boson,label=$\gamma^*$,label.side=left}{v3,v4}
    \fmf{fermion,label=$e^+$ (missed),label.side=left,label.dist=1}{v4,o2}
    \fmf{fermion,label=$e^-$,label.side=left}{v4,o3}
  \end{fmfgraph*}
  \end{fmffile}
}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)